# Reverse PTR record lookup not working with dig

Tags: email, reverse-dns, ptr-record, dig

As mentioned [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code/), having a Reverse PTR record is key for successful email sending and delivery from one's own server. In order to check if it's correctly set for my server, I tried:

```
dig -x 111.111.111.111    #  replace with the IP of a server
```

but the answer is:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.1-Ubuntu <<>> -x 111.111.111.111
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 29789
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.in-addr.arpa.     IN      PTR

;; Query time: 27 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep 10 14:51:32 CEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 54
```

I don't see anything that looks like a Reverse PTR record.

I tried with various IPs obtained from well-known websites: `dig -x 151.101.1.69` (obtained from `ping stackoverflow.com`), and it looks the same.

**Why can't I see any Reverse PTR record with `dig`?**

Comment: Not every IP address has a PTR record, and the one you picked by SO is one of those (it's not used for mail...). Do this check for something mail related. Also read https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/963/what-information-should-i-include-or-obfuscate-in-my-posts - if you had posted your IP, others could check if they get a good PTR for it .

Comment: @Sven I tried the same with the IP got from `ping smtp.gmail.com` (74.125.206.109) and it's the same. I even cannot find any single working IP that has such a record.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your client's DNS config.

Comment: "SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53" seems 127.0.0.1 isn't functioning properly.

Comment: Status code was `SERVFAIL`, check the logs?

Answer (score 0):

I tried from another server and it works:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.in-addr.arpa. 86399 IN     PTR     ns328xxxx.ip-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu.
```

so it should be a local server problem (as mentioned by someone in a comment).